# create a file system group pointing at a SAN

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, san, filetable

I am working with creating a FileTable in sql server 2012. I want to store the files on a SAN (Storage Area Network). I have mapped it to a drive on sql server.

To use the FileTable, I need to set up a file system group. I am using the following script but failing to get it correct:

```
ALTER DATABASE [MyDatabase]
ADD FILE 
(
    NAME = FileStreamFile,
    FILENAME= '\\123.456.789.001\MyFolder',
    MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED
    )
TO FileGroup MyFileStreamGroup
END
```

The entry I have for the FileName always seems to fail. How can I set up a FileStreamGroup to point at SAN and which in turn I will use to create a file table from it?

Answer (score 1):

As you have found, you can't put filestream files onto a remote drive using a UNC path.  Your best bet is to create a LUN on your SAN and connect to this via iSCSI, that way the drive will appear as local to SQL server but will still be physically located on the SAN.

You probably want to have a chat with your storage admin about doing this really.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to create a filegroup:

```
ALTER DATABASE [MyDatabase]
ADD FILEGROUP [MyFileStreamGroup]
```

Then you can add files to it:

```
ALTER DATABASE [MyDatabase]
ADD FILE ( 
    NAME = N'NewDataFile'
    ,FILENAME = N'\\123.456.789.001\MyFolder\NewDataFile.mdf' 
    ,SIZE = 1024KB
    ,FILEGROWTH = 1024KB
) TO FILEGROUP [MyFileStreamGroup]
```

And finally you can create tables:

```
CREATE TABLE [MyDatabase].[dbo].[NewTable] (
    [Id] int NOT NULL,
    [Text] varchar(50) NOT NULL
) ON [MyFileStreamGroup]
```

By specifying `ON [MyFileStreamGroup]` you force it to be created in that filegroup, which in turn will use the newly created file on the SAN. If you don't specify filegrop, the table will end up in the default one, which is usually called PRIMARY. If you want the new filegroup to be default, you can use:

```
ALTER DATABASE [MyDatabase]
MODIFY FILEGROUP [MyFileStreamGroup] DEFAULT
```

Comment: I get this error when I try that "The path '\\123.456.789.001\MyFolder\NewDataFile.mdf' cannot be used for FILESTREAM files. For information about supported paths, see SQL Server Books Online.2

Comment: Oh, I forgot to add CONTAINS FILESTREAM to ADD FILEGROUP. You are correct, I get the same error. It seems as it's not possible to have a filestream datafile on a remote path. I found this: http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/misconceptions-around-filestream-storage/ which says "The FILESTREAM data container for a database must be placed on an NTFS volume on locally-connected storage".